# Example of an infinite-dimensional geodesic NPC Space

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, metric-spaces, geometric-topology, metric-geometry

I just started reading [Ballmann's book](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm:978-1-4684-9159-3/1/1.pdf) on non-positive curvature spaces.  In it most, non-linear, examples of NPC spaces are negatively curved manifolds or specific graphs/discrete metric spaces, or buildings.

So, to gain intuition, what is a "down-to-earth"/interesting example of a metric space $(X,d)$ which:

- Has non-positive curvature (in the sense of Ballmann)
- X is not a topological vector space but it is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$.
- "X is not only a toy example but is interested in other areas of math...has reasonable "roots""

Comment: Do you know how to construct an infinite dimensional real hyperbolic space using an  indefinite quadratic form?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, actually I never heard of that (I'ld love to know more) also where does the infinite-dimensional real hyperbolic space originate from (like where does it find applications)?

Comment: A nonseparable version of this space was used to prove that Cremona group is not simple. But I doubt that this means anything to you.

Comment: It doesnt' but still; how can I see it is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to Hilbert space (this I don't see from the construction below).

Comment: It is not BL equivalent to a Hilbert space, for that, I do not think there are any "natural" examples.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is there at-least a quasi-symmetric homeomorphism from $\mathbb{H}$ to $\ell^2$?

Comment: I do not know. The nonexistence proofs that I know in finite-dimensional case do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll briefly sketch the construction of an infinite dimensional hyperbolic space mentioned by Moishe. Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space, and consider the space $V:=\mathbb R\oplus H$. We can equip $V$ with an inner product $\langle(\lambda_1,h_1),(\lambda_2,h_2)\rangle_V:=\lambda_1\lambda_2-\langle h_1,h_2\rangle_H$, turning it into a separable Hilbert space, with quadratic form, $Q(\cdot)=\|\cdot\|^2_V$. $V$ has a natural cone, $C=\{(\lambda,x)\in V: \|x\|_H<\lambda\}$. We can consider a slice of this cone $\mathcal H:=\{v\in C: Q(v)=1\}$. Finally, we equip $\mathcal H$ with a metric, $d(u,v):=\operatorname{arcosh}(\langle,u,v \rangle).$ The metric space $(\mathcal H,d)$ is known as the hyperboloid model of infinite dimensional hyperbolic space, and is the natural extension of [Minkowski's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of hyperbolic space in finite dimensions.